# What's the smallest DirectX installer I can distribute in my Software?

Tags: installation, directx, software-distribution

My application uses DirectX 9.0c. There are many installers for the end-user run-times, ranging from 400Kb to 100Mb+ and obviously I don't want to bloat my installer file. However, I believe there are potentially legal restrictions which mean I can't just distribute whichever MS installers I might choose.

[This](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=2DA43D38-DB71-4C1B-BC6A-9B6652CD92A3&displaylang=en) is the one I'd ideally like to include, is it the best /correct one?

Answer (score 1):

I think that program is not redistributable, you have to point people to the website.

There is a microsoft article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee416805(VS.85).aspx which talks about what the minimum files you need are. And yes, it's pain!

Comment: It's definitely possible to distribute an installer, this is done by ever PC game for years. The question is, which ones are allowed.

Comment: The web installer mentioned in the original article is not redistributable. The full installer is of course, and you only need to pick the parts of that you need, as the article I linked to mentioned